# 2D Array not being declared properly

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to take data from .ppm files and put filters on the images.
For some reason when I print the height and width of the image, it returns the values correctly, but when I put the data into a 2D array, it returns that the height is the same as the width even when it is not. Here is a snippet of relevant code. Does it have something to do with me initializing the Color 2D array?

```
    Color[][] totalData = null;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    while (fileScanner.hasNext()) {
        // Handles comments
        String line = fileScanner.nextLine();
        if ((line.startsWith("#"))) {
            continue;
        }

        width = fileScanner.nextInt();
        height = fileScanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println(width); //4
        System.out.println(height); //3

        //Skips the Max color value
        fileScanner.next();

        totalData = new Color[height][width];
        System.out.println(totalData[0].length); //4
        System.out.println(totalData[1].length); //4
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are printing the length of the first and the second rows of your array, and both are 4, since that's the width of your 2D array.

To see the height the and width (which are not the same), you should be printing :

```
System.out.println(totalData.length); // the number of rows (3)
System.out.println(totalData[0].length); // the length of each row (4)
```

Comment: So the first dimensional array is not represented by an index? Also, if this is true, then why does totalData[1] return anything?

Comment: `totalData[1]` is the second row of your 2D array. I'm not sure what you were asking in the first part of your comment.

Comment: I understand what you're saying. So then I should I define the totalData 2D array?

Comment: @HarrisonBergman Are you asking whether totalData should be a 2D array (as it currently is)? That depends on what data you plan to put in it.

Comment: Other places in my program I'm getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExceptions, so I thought it would be because of this

Comment: @HarrisonBergman I have no idea what other places in your program look like, so I can't say anything about them.